# Why do cabal configure?

Tags: haskell, cabal

In the [Cabal User Guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/) it says that Cabal is often compared with autoconf and automake since the command line interface for actually configuring and building packages follows the same steps steps:

```
./configure --prefix=...
make
make install
```

compared to

```
cabal configure --prefix=...
cabal build
cabal install
```

My understanding is that `./configure` uses a config file (produced by autoconf) to adapt the make process to the environment in which it will run and also to check dependencies. So `./configure` therefore always have an "input" to conform to. But if `cabal configure` is not given any arguments what does it do, and why is it necessary before running `cabal build`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cabal configure` step does at least two things I know of:

- Check that the package description parses OK.
- Check that all required dependencies are already installed (and report an error if not).

Basically it's running the constraint solver to decide exactly which packages you're going to build against. (E.g., if you have several versions of `ByteString` installed, which version are you going to use? Well it might depend on which version the packages you depend on are expecting...)

Also I believe it's possible to supply options at configure time which change exactly which features of the package get built (but I don't have experience with this).

I think originally you *had* to call `configure` before you could call `build`, but I believe now the `cabal` command-line tool does that step for you automatically in many cases. (E.g., `cabal run` now seems to automatically reconfigure if the package description file is newer than the configuration DB.)